# Vue Single Page Application Bootstrap 5 Nav not shrinking on mobile

Tags: css, navbar, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I am building a Single Page Website using Vue 3, and I am using Bootstrap 5 for css. The navbar is one of the standard templates on the [bootstrap examples page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/navbars/). My issue is that on mobile, when the collapsed navbar is exposed, it doesn't close. I assume this is because it's a single page application, and the nav holds it's state.

I would like the navbar to automatically collapse on the click of one of the router links. I have seen a number of answers on other StackOverflow threads that use Jquery, but I would like to use plain JS if possible. If there is a fix with bootstrap classes, that would also be great.

I have tried adding the `data-bs-toggle` and the `data-bs-target`to the router links, but that just breaks the router links, and doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance

Here is the html for the nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="bike" :src="bikeSVG" /></a>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="navbar-toggler"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/" class="nav-link active">Home</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'Events' }" class="nav-link active"
              >Events</router-link
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div v-if="!this.$store.state.auth.status.loggedIn">
          <router-link
            class="nav-item mx-2 btn btn-yellow fw-bold"
            :to="{ name: 'LogIn' }"
            >Log In</router-link
          >
          <router-link
            class="mx-2 btn btn-yellow fw-bold"
            :to="{ name: 'SignUp' }"
            >Sign Up</router-link
          >
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-red dropdown-toggle"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              Profile
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
              <li>
                <router-link
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  type="button"
                  :to="{ name: 'Profile' }"
                  >Your Profile</router-link
                >
              </li>
              <hr />
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" @click="logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: As I got no response, I fixed it in a rather silly way... I added a watcher to my route, and it changes the class list of the nav to hide it every time the route changes: 
`if (this.$refs.NavBar.classList.length === 3) this.$refs.toggleBtn.click();`